# Way to fill collection with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have two example classes

```
class ClassToResolve
{
    private List<CollectionItem> _coll;

    public ClassToResolve(List<CollectionItem> coll)
    {
        _coll = coll;
    }
}

class CollectionItem
{
    //...
}
```

and I need to resolve ClassToResolve

```
var classToResolve = new ClassToResolve(
            new List<CollectionItem>()
                {
                    new CollectionItem(),
                    new CollectionItem(),
                    new CollectionItem()
                }

            );
```

Now I resolve it in a way

```
var classToResolve = new ClassToResolve(
            new List<CollectionItem>()
                {
                    unity.Resolve<CollectionItem>(),
                    unity.Resolve<CollectionItem>(),
                    unity.Resolve<CollectionItem>()
                }
            );
```

Is there a way to resolve ClassToResolve with Unity using dynamic registration?

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense. Why are you injecting multiple identical instances into the `ClassToResolve`?

Comment: They are not identical. They are identical only in the example. I simplified the example. In fact, this list of objects that inherit / implement from one base class / interface, or a list of differently configured objects.
This is very similar to the pattern design "Director" where ClassToResolve = Director and CollectionItem=Strategy (like IRunnable)

Comment: Are they all of the same interface or of different interfaces? What do you *actually* want to happen?

Comment: This is a very common use case. One object uses a list of other objects. But the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Unity will understand that `T[]` (array) dependencies are a list of things (but not `IEnumerable<T>`, nor `List<T>`). When you change the constructor of `ClassToResolve` to take an `CollectionItem[]` instead of a `List<CollectionItem>` you can configure your `CollectionItem` types as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<CollectionItem, CollectionItemA>("a");
container.RegisterType<CollectionItem, CollectionItemB>("b");
container.RegisterType<CollectionItem, CollectionItemC>("c");
container.RegisterType<CollectionItem, CollectionItemD>("d");
```

The trick here is to name all the registrations. A default (nameless) registration will never be part of a sequence dependency in Unity.

Now you can resolve `ClassToResolve` without the need to register it:

```
container.Resolve<ClassToResolve>();
```

If you rather inject `List<CollectionItem>` you can add the following registration:

```
container.RegisterType<IList<CollectionItem>, CollectionItem[]>();
```

And for `IEnumerable<CollectionItem>` you can add the following line:

```
container
  .RegisterType<IEnumerable<CollectionItem>, CollectionItem[]>();
```

Comment: -1 You're wrong Unity doesn't understand IEnumerable<T> unless you register it explicitly.

Comment: @Hasan: You are right. I was too quick. Unity understands `T[]` by default, not `IEnumerable<T>`. I fixed it.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what i need! Would be correct container.RegisterType<IList<CollectionItem>, CollectionItem[]>();

Comment: The name parameter is key!

Answer (score 0):

[@Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven)'s answer is perfectly correct, I just want to suggest another way to tackle the issue.

For the sake of a better and cleaner code, it is worth it to define an interface for all the collection items.

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public abstract class MyClassBase : IMyClass
{
    abstract void DoSomething();
    // more code for the base class if you need it.
}

public class MyClassA : MyClassBase
{
    void virtual DoSomething()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}

public class MyClassB : MyClassBase
{
    void virtual DoSomething()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}

public class MyClassC : MyClassBase
{
    void virtual DoSomething()
    {
        // implementation here
    }
}

// etc.
```

Now the registration code for Unity container would be much more easier:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().
        Where(type => typeof(IMyClass).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.TypeName,
    WithLifetime.PerResolve);

container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IMyClass>, IMyClass[]>();
```

and the resolve code is the same:

```
var allOfMyClasses = container.ResolveAll<IMyClass>();
```

I hope Microsoft add `IEnumerable<>` support to the next version of Unity so we won't need to register `IEnumerable<IMyClass>`.

Comment: For code samples, could you replace the "var" with the concrete datatype(s)?  I greatly appreciate this answer, but "var" within code samples ... doesn't helper the reader IMHO.  Thanks.  I'm guessing it is IEnumerable<IMyClass>, but it would be nice to see what you have.

Answer (score -1):

You should register you class in unity

```
container.RegisterType()
```

It's better to use interface

Comment: Registration details are not present in the example. Because, this is the question - how to register this collection for auto-resolving it with Unity?

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
class ClassToResolve:IEnumerable<CollectionItem>
{
    private List<CollectionItem> _coll;

    public ClassToResolve(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _coll = container.ResolveAll<CollectionItem>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<CollectionItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _coll.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(CollectionItem)
    {
        this._coll.Add(CollectionItem);
    }
}

now register you class
```

Comment: Thank you. But I prefer do not use Unity as a service locator.