# Dependency Injection to resolve dependency with runtime data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using simple injector for my web api project.  I have a service which requires a session token in order for it to instantiate.

```
public class CustomerService
{
   public CustomerService(Auth auth, IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
   {
        // make post call to another web api for validation
        SomeWebApiCallToValidateAuth.vaildate(auth);
   }
}
```

So for this service, it requires an auth token and a repositoryFactory.  I want it to be able to inject the auth parameter (which comes from the http web request) and at the same time to resolve the repository factory with the specified implemented thats registered to the container.

But I am not sure how to register this with simple injector or if there is a way around it.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not have a factory for this service as well? Inject the Repository Factory in there, and call a method with the runtime data. The other option would be to inspect your separation of concerns. There's not enough info in the question for that, so I can't point you in that direction.

Comment: You should have a method in the service which takes the token as parameter does the validation. With the current approach the object initialization will fail if the validation fails and that will break the entire control flow. If you still want to go ahead with this approach it will be very tricky coz you need to put the token to some place so that DI container read that token to initialize the service. Not sure which DI container has that support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current approach has several downsides:

- You inject runtime data into the constructor of your component, which [can lead to complications](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).
- You make use of an *Abstract Factory*, which [is often not the best abstraction](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/).
- Your constructor invokes validation, while it [should do nothing other than storing its incoming dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). This way you can [compose your object graphs with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

Concerning the factory: Inject an `IRepository` rather than an `IRepositoryFactory`. This might require you to hide the real repository behind a proxy, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42409598/264697).

Concerning the `Auth` value, it depends on the need, but if the `Auth` value is an important part of the `API` of `CustomerService`, this justifies adding `Auth` as argument on the methods of `CustomerService`. If it is an implementation detail, inject an `IAuthProvider` abstraction of some sort that allows you to retrieve the value at runtime (after the object graph is built). Again, this all is described in [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).