# Pass array of types to constructor using Unity Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have several classes which derived from interface

```
public interface IMetadataItem
{
  Do();
}

public class MyClass1 : IMetadataItem
{
  public void Do()
  {
  }
}

public class MyClass2 : IMetadataItem
{
 public void Do()
 {
 }
}
```

I would like to bind these classes of IMetadataItem interface to constructor of another class

```
public class MetadataService: IMetadataService
{
  public MetadataService(IEnumerable<IMetadataItem> metadataItems)
  {
    //metadataItems always has zero(0) items
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I always get empty IEnumerable list.

The Unity config look like

```
     container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(type => typeof(IMetadataItem).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
            WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
            WithName.TypeName,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);

        container.RegisterType<IMetadataService, Services.MetadataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedArrayParameter<IMetadataItem>()) );
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi friend, How many item in the array you want to pass?

Comment: It would be around 15 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unity v5:

You can remove the 2nd parameter `InjectionConstructor` from `RegisterType`

```
container.RegisterType<IMetadataService, MetadataService>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

For v4:

Unity does not internally understand `IEnumerable<>` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6317570/1515209)) so you will need to change the constructor to take an array instead of an enumerable

```
public class MetadataService: IMetadataService
{
    public MetadataService(IMetadataItem[] metadataItems)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I get exception when remove InjectionConstructor.

System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PC.Domain.Interfaces.IMetadataItem], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Comment: @Tomas what version of Unity are you using?

Comment: I use 4.1 version, should I upgrade to 5?

Comment: @Tomas I've tested it with 5. Before you do upgrade, older versions of Unity didn't internally understand `IEnumerable<>`, you could try `IMetadataItem[]` in the constructor of `MetadataService`

Comment: That did the trick! When I was coding I have used IMetadataItem[] but Resharper suggested refactoring to IEnumerable<IMetadataItem>. I didn't thought  that it would make difference.